# My cron job doesn't work - Could not open input file error

Tags: woocommerce, cron, cron-task

I have a woocommerce website and use a dropshipping plugin. Because I am on a shared server I tried to set up a cron job, to reduce CPU usage of my site.
I checked the dropshipping plugin and they have 5 scheduled cron jobs and I wanted to add that schedule to my set but I am not sure if I did it correctly.

So they have the following structure in my cpanel:

public_html/wp-content/plugins/bdroppy/src/CronJob/Jobs

In the CronJob folder they have Jobs folder and 1 file CronJob.php. [cronjob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXcq1.jpg)

Under the Jobs folder they have 6 php files. [cronjob-jobs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRjWE.jpg)

So I added all task what was in the CronJob/Jobs folder to my siteground account:

php /home/******/www/ *********/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bdroppy/src/CronJob/Jobs/QueueJob.php

but I got an error "Could not open input file error" for each task.
Should I add CronJob.php also to the cron job command?
Hope I explained properly and thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you have disabled `WP-Cron` because of performance reasons, and instead you want to run `wp-cron.php` directly from your shared server. Running `wp-cron.php` will take care of executing any events that have been scheduled using the `wp_schedule_event` function. Including the events of the drop shipping plugin you are using. In fact, the plugin is registering its events in the `admin_footer` hook. So as long as you have activated the plugin, you don't need to do anything else.

The correct command for the cron job (to set up on your server) is:

```
php -q  /home/******/www/ *********/public_html/wp-cron.php
```

In order to check that the plugin events (i.e. `bdroppy_queues_event`, `bdroppy_change_catalog_event`, `bdroppy_update_catalog_event`, `bdroppy_update_product_event` and `bdroppy_sync_order_event`) have been correctly scheduled, you can either use a dedicated plugin (e.g. [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/)), or use the [WP command line interface](https://wp-cli.org/) (`wp-cli`), which should be available on your shared server too.

If you want to use `wp-cli`, you need to:

- ssh into your shared server;
- navigate to the `public_html` directory;
- run this command: `wp cron event list`

For more information on how to use `wp-cli` to list scheduled cron events, check its [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/cron/event/list/).

Comment: Hi Diego, thank you for your explanation, appreciate it. I tried to contact with Siteground but they are not really give us any proper information to understand what was the problem or how it is working. So now I added what you suggested and it looks like working.

Comment: It looks like Siteground allows you to use the `wp-cli` in a cron job (see this [tutorial](https://www.siteground.co.uk/tutorials/wordpress/real-cron-job/) for more details). Might be a better option than using `php` directly. And don't forget to disable `WP-Cron` in your `wp-config.php` (i.e. `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`). Are the WP events correctly running now?